# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox - installation-troubles on OpenSuse-Linux version 12.1

Tags: perl, makefile, mechanize, gnu-make, opensuse

good day dear fellow perl-programmers.

i have serious install-troubles with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox on OpenSuse 12.1 (which is a linux system that is used here in Europe): see the issues that i noticed in the command-line:

```
 cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.960001)                                                                                                                             
Enter 'h' for help.                                                                                                                                                                             

cpan[1]> install  WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;     
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://artfiles.org/cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://artfiles.org/cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Thu, 09 Feb 2012 23:13:21 GMT
  HTTP::Date not available
..............
  New CPAN.pm version (v1.9800) available.
  [Currently running version is v1.960001]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


..............................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://artfiles.org/cpan.org/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Going to write /root/.cpan/Metadata
Warning: Cannot install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;, don't know what it is.
Try the command


 i /WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

well - what does the programme want to tell me?

i am a bit lost

**btw** what does that mean: do i also need to **install mozRepl**

**update** see  tbe update - what **do ya think?**

```
cpan[2]> ^Cinstall  WWW::Mechanize::Firefox
Caught SIGINT, trying to continue
Running install for module 'WWW::Mechanize::Firefox'
Running make for C/CO/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz
Giving up on '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CO/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz'
Note: Current database in memory was generated on Thu, 09 Feb 2012 23:13:21 GMT

cpan[3]>
```

Comment: Your first one failed because there is no module named `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;`. Leave off the semicolon and try it again. I don't know what's going on with your `^C` and `SIGINT` in your second problem. Just start from scratch (or just do `cpan install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` from the command-line).

Comment: g day dear CanSpice - many many thanks i will re-try it. THX for your great support- I come back and report all the findings. Greetings from  good old europe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the system Perl. Install from the standard repository or [`devel:languages:perl`](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/perl/openSUSE_12.1/) first.

```
sudo zypper install perl-WWW-Mechanize
```

Fall back to CPAN if the module is not packaged yet.

---

[MozRepl](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki). Use a search engine next time for such a basic thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; that is the correct way to install a module using the `cpan` script. The important lines are:

```
⁝
/usr/bin/make -- OK
⁝
/usr/bin/make test -- OK
⁝
/usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

They state that `make`, `make test` and `make install` ran successfully.

Comment: i now want to test a little script - with mechanize::firefox . but see: Can't locate WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at test_3.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test_3.pl line5

Comment: Perl is unable to find the module in the list of directories it searches for modules. That normally means that the module in question is not installed. If that is the case, try installing it.