# Make [GNU-Make gcc or what ever] on OpenSuse 12.1 - how to accomplish

Tags: linux, perl, makefile, mechanize, opensuse

good dear fello Perl-Programmers, hope you are all right!

l...there are a lot of problems here: how do i install the module Mechanize::Firefox on  OpenSuse 12.1

It seems that  bunch of dependencies and all configurations are necessary. Way to much 
Besides the installatin of Mechanize::Firefox i also did the intallation of MozRepl..I've installed it through firefox...as an add-on

Well - i have big bigtroubles with MAKE what do you think - i guess that i have a bad bad make...

```
      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/52-selector-relative.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/53-mech-capture-js-error.t    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/55-basic-auth.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/60-mech-cookies.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/65-is_visible.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/65-mech-meta.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/70-download-url.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/70-mech-png.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/70-real-status.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/75-save_url-cookies.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/99-changes.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 2 tests but ran 0.
t/99-examples.t                 (Wstat: 3328 Tests: 14 Failed: 13)
  Failed tests:  1-3, 5-14
  Non-zero exit status: 13
t/mechanize/autocheck.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/mechanize/content.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/rt65615.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/select.t                      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=72, Tests=59,  5 wallclock secs ( 0.25 usr  0.10 sys +  4.08 cusr  0.62 csys =  5.05 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 67/72 test programs. 13/59 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Fehler 2
  CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (MozRepl::RemoteObject); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
linux-wyee:/home/martin/perl #
```

Guess that i nee a better / make ö- probably the make is missing at all??!!
i do some further investigations and come back here - greetings

Comment: haven't you asked this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233880/wwwmechanizefirefox-installation-troubles-on-opensuse-linux-version-12-1

Comment: The output you've shown is the tail end of the test output summary.  It doesn't show what actually failed in the build step.  That was likely at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when MozRepl::RemoteObject cannot be loaded. Install MozRepl for the system, not your user only.